# Lake Visitor Modeling by Neural Networks

Tags: matlab, neural-network, time-series

Let's say I want to model the amount of visitors at an arbitrary lake at specific time.

Given Data:

- Time Series of Amount of Visitors for 12 lakes.
- Weather Time Series for the 12 lakes
- Number of Trees at lake
- Percentage of grass/stone ground of the beach.

Hereby I want to use a Neural Network (NN) to model the amount of visitors and I have some essential questions which I want to introduce step by step. Note that the visitor time series shall not be used!

1) we only use the Inputs:

- Time of Day
- Day of Week

So there is two inputs and one output. I read of a rule of thumb which says that the hidden neurons should be chosen as

`#input>=neurons>=#output`.

Is the number of inputs here 2 or is it an estimate of the real amount of dependent variables (as weather, mood of persons, economical situation, ....). If yes so I should choose my hidden neurons as 1 or 2, correct?

2) If I want to include lake specific parameters as the number of treas or the ground ratio, can I just add these as additional inputs (constant for each of the twelve lakes) or would that not help for some reason? How could I assure that there is a causal connection between these inputs and the output?

3) For weather since it is a time series which weather values should I use. How do I get the optimal delay for example. Would Granger Causality be a mean to determine that?

Hope you can help. I just wanna discuss on the strength of NNs for modeling and want to hear your opinion. I would use Matlabs Neural Network Toolbox for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: or you only use 2 inputs or you use more. If you want more variables (as number of trees) that is a new input to the NN. You have a doubt if variables are dependant or not? use PCA.

Comment: As far as I know PCA transforms inter-correlated inputs to non-correlated principal components which will then be used as inputs.
So what if a principal component does not have any causal relation to the target function of the neural network. Still the NN would try finding the best fit but not reject this input. So how can I be sure that I only feed in the relevant inputs/principal components then?